# Everything is okay in local drive but these code simply don't work in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I tried to code the responsive menu in local drive and everything is working without error.

However, the responsive menu simply doesn't work in Wordpress blankslate. Please help. I attach the comprehensive code in the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TissuePaper/op5v03mu/1/). Thanks.

My HTML snippet

```
<div id="nav_bar">
    <div class="group">
        <label for="toggle-1" class="title">Title-1</label><input type="checkbox" id="toggle-1">
        <div class="menu_list">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#Menu-A1">Menu-A1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Menu-A2">Menu-A2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="group">
        <label for="toggle-2" class="title">Title-2</label><input type="checkbox" id="toggle-2">
        <div class="menu_list">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#Menu-B1">Menu-B1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Menu-B2">Menu-B2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Menu-B3">Menu-B3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="group">
        <label for="toggle-3" class="title">Title-3</label><input type="checkbox" id="toggle-3">
        <div class="menu_list">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#Menu-C1">Menu-C1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="group">
        <label for="toggle-4" class="title">Title-4</label><input type="checkbox" id="toggle-4">
        <div class="menu_list">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#Menu-D1">Menu-D1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Menu-D2">Menu-D2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS snippet

```
@media all and (min-width:100px) and (max-width:1024px) {
 #nav_bar {
        display: none;
    }

    #menu {
        display: block;
    }

    #toggle:checked + #nav_bar {
        display: block;
    }

    .group {
        text-align: left;
        position: block;
    }

    .group:hover {
        background-color: gray;
    }

    .title {
        display: block;
        padding: 15px;
    }

    .title:active {
        color: red;
    }

    .menu_list {
        width: 100%;
    }

    [id^="toggle"]:checked + .menu_list {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

I have been modifying the codes, yet I still couldn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issue yes when you used this jsfiddle code as HTML it works but when you add in theme of Wordpress it is not working two issue here

1. nav class which is already added by WordPress and it's CSS so what i do i add this code to twenty twelve theme and the css of nav class in original is

   nav {
   background-color: lightcoral;
   display: block;
   }

   To
   nav {
   background-color: lightcoral;
   display: block;
   overflow: unset !important;
   }

and 2 is the + operator in css i change to ~ this work so here is full updated css

Click the help icon above to learn more.

```
*/
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

nav {
    background-color: lightcoral;
    display: block;
    overflow: unset !important;
}
#menu {
    padding: 1%;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 180%;
    display: none;
}
[id^="toggle"] {
    display: none;
}


/*  NAVAGATION TITLE */

.group {
    position: relative;
}

.title {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
    font-size: 120%;
}

/* MENU LIST */

.menu_list {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px grey;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1;
}

.menu_list ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.menu_list ul li:hover {
    background-color: lightgray;
}

.menu_list ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    color: black;
}

/* FOR MOBILE DEVICE */

@media all and (min-width:100px) and (max-width:1024px) {
    #nav_bar {
        display: none;
    }

    #menu {
        display: block;
    }

    #toggle:checked~#nav_bar {
        display: block;
    }


    .group {
        text-align: left;
        position: block;
    }

    .group:hover {
        background-color: gray;
    }

    .title {
        display: block;
        padding: 15px;
    }

    .title:active {
        color: red;
    }

    .menu_list {
        width: 100%;
    }

    [id^="toggle"]:checked~.menu_list {
        display: block;
    }
}

/* FOR DESKTOP AND LAPTOP */

@media all and (min-width:1025px) {
    .group {
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: left;

    }

    .group:hover .menu_list {
        display: block;
    }

    .title {
        width: 150px;
        padding: 25px;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .title:hover {
        background-color: gray;
    }

    .menu_list ul li {
        width: 250px;
    }

}
```

No update in HTML use same one check the attachment screenshot[image]

[image]

[image]